# Visual Studio 2019:Why my IDE can't check header syntax?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

My IDE is Visual Studio 2019.I find it can't check the header syntax,so if I forget to enter a ' ; ' ,it can't remind me to correct the error.Instead,it will cause a lot of useless error such as "The identifier cannot be found : cout".

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can help if you don't show the code you are compiling. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: ***it will cause a lot of useless error such as*** I ignore the Errors List and instead read the errors from the Output tab. That way the errors are both more verbose and also in the correct order.